# Anchor Build Error: failed to select a version for the requirement `aho-corasick = "^1.0.0"

Tags: anchor, solana-cli, build-bpf

`````
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `aho-corasick = "^1.0.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.7.20, 0.7.19, 0.7.18, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `regex v1.8.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `regex = "^1.0"` (locked to 1.8.1) of package `anchor-attribute-access-control v0.27.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `anchor-attribute-access-control = "^0.27.0"` (locked to 0.27.0) of package `anchor-lang v0.27.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `anchor-lang = "^0.27.0"` (locked to 0.27.0) of package `solana-twitter v0.1.0 (/Users/roshanwazare/projects/solana-twitter/programs/solana-twitter)````
`````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello [Roshan](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/4746/roshan-wazare)
I was just sitting with a very similar problem. For reference, I'm using a MacBook Pro 2020 with Ventura 13.3.1 installed.

The pitfall for me was that I installed a older version of solana-release with the command, `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.9.5/install)"`.

However, reading the [installation guide](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#macos--linux), I could see that I should have been installing version 1.15.2

Installing the newer version fixed the problem for me, I hope it helps you too.